# To stop auto generated IPv6 link local address

Tags: ipv6, autoconf

How can I stop assigning of link local IPv6 address? I have tried to do it by disabling the `accept_ra` and `autoconf` options, but it is not working.

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable just `fe80::/64` prefix addresses?  Others are OK?

Comment: yes I want to disable this because if I assign some other static IPv6 and I give command ifconfig, it will show "TWO" IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Link local addresses are an important part of IPv6. Disabling them will break IPv6.

Comment: But I am giving another link address. If somehow that link address does not generate automatically, it will cause problem to my device so for that reason I am assigning one static link local IPv6.

Comment: Ah, right. That makes more sense ☺